# Duplicate value of input for multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, forms

i need put value of general price
for all inputs but only take the value for 1st input.

[image]

Code :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#GPrecio').change(function () {
   $('#Precio').val($(this).val());
   });
   </script>
```

HTML :

```
<input type='text' size='3' name='GPrecio' id='GPrecio'>
$table.="<td>Precio : <br><input type='text' size='3' name='Precio[]' id='Precio'></td>";
```

Thank for answers and the time.

Comment: Do you want all the below input to have the same value as the top one?

Comment: Yes, the value of the top its GPrecio, but with this jQuery function only take 1st value of Precio like image, and need put to all.

Comment: Firstly I would suggest you to add the code for your table rows <tr>. If all of them are using the same id, instead switch to class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will take the value of `#GPrecio` and apply it to all `input name=Precio[]` elements

```
$('#GPrecio').blur(function () {
  $('[name="Precio[]"]').val($(this).val());
});
```

Also, if you have more than one element with `id="Precio"`, that is a problem. Better to not use IDs unless you need them. Is there a reason you're using the same ID for each? You would be better off using a data-attribute, like `<input type='text' size='3' name='Precio[]' data-inputtype='Precio'>`, in which case your function could be refined to:

```
$('#GPrecio').blur(function () {
  $('[data-inputtype="Precio"]').val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Thank you. but have this error in the console and not work : Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=Precio[]]

Answer (score 0):

As you can't use multiple same id, change it to class first:

```
 <input type='text' size='3' name='Precio[]' class='Precio'>
```

And then jQuery trigger:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#GPrecio').change(function () {
    var gpval = $(this).val();
    $('.Precio').each(function( index ) {
        $(this).val(gpval);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to use `classes` instead of `ids` if you are going to use the same value.

Your input row could be like this:

```
<input type='text' size='3' name='Precio[]' class='Precio'>
```

Assuming `Precio` is the class name for all your inputs in the table row.

```
   $('#GPrecio').change(function () {
  let newValue = $(this).val();
$(".Precio").each(function() {
    $(this).val(newValue);
})   
});
```

Comment: Thank you, for help. But i have error in console with this code : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).forEach is not a function